# Pipfile.lock is out of date.

Tags: python, heroku, pipfile

Trying to push a python script to heroku, It's complaining that my pipfile.lock is out of date. I'm using pipenv to manage dependencies, and I've tried running pipenv lock to update the lock file to no avail.

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 2.39 KiB | 817.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Found python-3.6.5, removing
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.15
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2.
remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (c7d2bf) is out of date. Expected: (29c137).
remote:        Aborting deploy.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to bot_testbed.
remote:

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as Consolas!
To https://git.heroku.com/peopleoftherealms.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bot_testbed.git
```

Comment: Run "pipenv lock", it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

A simple `pipenv install` was the solution when this was my problem. I used windows ubuntu, but it should be universal.

Comment: It has worked for me as well.